# Mockito mock final static inner class constructor

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

using Mockito 4, how can we mock below Builder class constructor?

```
  val alias = "some string"
  val purpose = 1 
  val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, purpose)
  val spec = builder.build()
```

Comment: `static inner` is a contradiction in terms. There is nothing here that is either `static` or `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

In Mockito 4 you can use `mockConstructor()`. In Kotlin it would be something like this:

```
mockConstruction(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder::class.java)
```